# Flashing cloud effect on LED strip/RaspberryPI

Tags: raspberry-pi3, led

I have a LED strip with 20 LEDs and RPI3 B+

now I need to tweak the code below to flash LEDs randomly in various intensity and colours from (80,0,150) to (200,0,255),,

I have all hardware setup well, using adafruit library ws281x bud don't know how to code an infinite loop of flashing (not blinking)..

I've found a project I really want to be close to: https://youtu.be/EoGVQl3SjGY

my code for now is:

```
from rpi_ws281x import *
import random

# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT      = 20      # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN        = 10      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!).
#LED_PIN        = 10      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (10 uses SPI /dev/spidev0.0).
LED_FREQ_HZ    = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA        = 10      # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 255   # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT     = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL    = 0       # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53

strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ,LED_DMA,LED_INVERT,LED_BRIGHTNESS,LED_CHANNEL)
strip.begin()

for x in range(0,LED_COUNT):
    while True:
        R = random.randint(80,200)
        B = random.randint(150,255)
        strip.setPixelColor(x,Color(R,0,B))

strip.show()
```

---

So my question - is there anyone who know how I would tweak the code to get such an effect?

Thanks in advance to all to push me in right way..

Ereen

tried find an effect on the web

Answer (score 0):

```
from rpi_ws281x import *
import random

# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT      = 20      # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN        = 10      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!).
#LED_PIN        = 10      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (10 uses SPI /dev/spidev0.0).
LED_FREQ_HZ    = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA        = 10      # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 255   # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT     = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL    = 0       # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53

strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ,LED_DMA,LED_INVERT,LED_BRIGHTNESS,LED_CHANNEL)
strip.begin()

while True: # <- Start the infinite loop, each iteration gets a new random color
    for x in range(LED_COUNT): # <- iterate through your LED counts
        R = random.randint(80,200) # <- Random RED color
        B = random.randint(150,255) # <- Random BLUE color
        strip.setPixelColor(x,Color(R,0,B)) # <- Set the pixel color

    strip.show() # <- Show the pixel color for each LED index
    # Do something here, my guess is a timer to keep the LEDs on for a set time, then turn them off.
    # Next would be another timer to wait before restarting the loop (unless you don't want to wait)
```

I believe this should get you started. This creates an endless while loop that gets the random colors for red and blue, applies the colors to the strip, then shows the colors by turning on the strip.